# HTTP response code for REST GET - subresource not found (but not referenced by identifier)

Tags: rest, http, null, response

I'm building a REST API and have a dilemma around the returning response code to a GET operation. 
I've found many examples and answers online but not for my particular scenario. 
Here is what I have found and understand so far:

1. if returning an empty list (say **/library/authors/{authorId}/books**) an empty list with a response code 200 will suffice
2. if requesting a specific resource with an id ( say **/library/authors/{authorId}/books/{bookId}** ) the response will be empty with a 404

That summarizes most of my use cases and I am fine with it.

However, what happens if I access a sub-resource without an id?

For example, for arguments sake, let's say the author can have many books, but only one auto-biography. He either has one or he doesn't. I don't expect the user to pass in the auto-biography id because the system can figure out on its own if one exists, the endpoint is something like this:

**GET /library/authors/{authorId}/auto-biography**

If the author exists but he has no autobiography (it is NULL), would the http response code be:

- **204** (empty content)
- **404** (resource does not exist)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working through the semantics

```
GET /library/authors/1/auto-biography
```

`/library/authors/1/auto-biography` is an identifier.  The [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) itself is some concept like "the auto biography of author 1"; notice that we can talk about the resource even though it may not actually exist yet.

> A resource can map to the empty set, which allows references to be made to a concept before any realization of that concept exists

The thing that appears in the body of the HTTP response isn't the resource, but a *representation* of the resource.

So now look at the status codes

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

[204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.

A loose analogy: suppose you try to get the contents of a file.  `404` is semantically aligned with FileNotFound; `204` indicates the file is zero bytes long.

`404` would normally be accompanied by "a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition."  It indicates that the client tried to use a link that shouldn't have been available.

`204`, on the other hand, doesn't have anything -- the representation is zero bytes long, how could there be data.  It's a special case of a `200` response, advising the client (and intermediary components) that the response body is intentionally left blank.